# cny70 with 40106 and PIC, only detects 1 time every time I reset

Tags: pic, proximity-sensor

I am using a PIC18F2550, a CNY70 and a 40106. (Schematics below)

The problem is that when I turn on the circuit, the first time the CNY70 detects something works perfectly (I have 1 led in every B output, except for B0 that is the interrupt input). The LEDs turn on for a very short time and then turn off. But when I try to do it again, the voltage of the CNY70 output changes how it has to, but the 40106 output only change from 10mV to 100mV. Also, I have changed the CNY70 and I have the same problem. I checked all the connections several times but i can't find anything wrong.

I tried 3 different configurations with the CNY70 and the 40106:

1. Without capacitor:

[image]

2. With capacitor between 40106 input and Gnd:

[image]

3. With capacitor between Vcc and Gnd: (I can't post more links - the same as the 1º but with a 100nf ceramic capacitor between Vcc and Gnd)

I use a PIC18F2550. The program is very simple, right now is only for testing the sensor:

```
#int_EXT
void  EXT_isr(void) {
  output_B (0b11111110);
  delay_ms (300);
  output_B (0b00000000);
}

void main() {

   setup_adc_ports(AN0|VSS_VDD);
   setup_adc(ADC_CLOCK_INTERNAL);
   setup_spi(SPI_SS_DISABLED);
   setup_wdt(WDT_OFF);
   setup_timer_1(T1_DISABLED);
   setup_timer_3(T3_DISABLED|T3_DIV_BY_1);
   setup_ccp1(CCP_OFF);
   setup_comparator(NC_NC_NC_NC);
   port_b_pullups(TRUE);

   set_tris_b(0x01);

   enable_interrupts(INT_EXT);
   enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);

   while(true){}
   }
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Turn on the circuit
2. CNY70 to air (open). it's output is 4.5V
3. 40106 input is then 4.5V so the output is 0V (10mV). (B0 = 0)
4. Now I cover the CNY70 (close). It's output is 150mv.
5. 40106 input is then 150mv so the output is 5V. (B0 = 1)
6. B1-B7 output high, turning on the 7 leds for a few ms.
7. I put the CNY70 to air again (open). it's output is 4.5V
8. 40106 input is then 4.5V so the ouput is 0V (10mv) (B0 = 0)
9. I conver The CNY70 again (close). It's output is 150mv.
10. 40106 input is then 150mv, BUT the output is only about 100mv. (B0 = 0)

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I forgot to say that I'm still studying english so is probable that I did some mistakes.

Comment: Please consider completing your user profile. You need at least 10 reputation points to get past the new user restrictions (which are primarily spam-prevention tools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item 10 indicates port B0 has become an output and is being driven low, and is fighting the 40106. I don't use the CCS compiler, which is apparently what you're using, but consider this description of the output_B function:

[image]

So it looks like you should use the #use*_io directive rather than (or in addition to) TRIS to set the direction of the port pins (specifically #use fixed_IO).

These non-standard C things are *irritating*

Comment: Thank *you* for providing a (somewhat rare) lucid description of the issues. Welcome, and don't forget to "accept" the answer which best answers the query (the check mark).

Comment: In case you were curious, I was trying to make a propeller clock. Now thanks to you it works very well: http://i.imgur.com/00wVQQw.jpg

Comment: @Leingen One day I knew my name would be in lights.. thanks.